# iOS 6 - Deal with black stripes on top and bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I use phonegap 2.0 to develop mobile applications. Now, iOS 6 poped out, but there is no new Ghonegap release yet. I wonder how to deal with the (default) black stripes on top and bottom because my app is designed for ios 5 family which has a smaller display.

Comment: The first step is to wait until iOS 6 actually comes out and the NDA is lifted...

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508775/phonegap-and-iphone-5-remove-top-and-bottom-black-stripes)

Comment: +1 @ErezRabih, thanks, I came up with that solution last night. I wish you put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Erez Rabih points:

All apps that do not include the `Default-568h@2x.png` file are displayed in a letter box. Include the `Default-568h@2x.png` will make your app fill the screen on 4" retina devices.

The web browser view of the PhoneGap should fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app was working well on a 4 inch screen before I deleted the launcher image.

Answer (score 1):

Well surely they will remain as black stripes until you get a chance to distribute an iOS6-friendly version of your app once a new Phonegap release comes out?