# PhoneGap and iPhone 5: Remove top and bottom black stripes

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile

I'm using PhoneGap to build a mobile app for iOS.
Lately I downloaded the new Xcode and ran the app on iPhone5 simulator. The app is working well, but there are two black stripes and the bottom and top of the app. I know that this is Apple's way to be backward compatible with older apps which were not designed for iPhone 5's 4-inch screen.

Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app fully exploit the new 4-inch screen iPhone 5?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All apps that do not include the `Default-568h@2x.png` file are displayed in a letter box.
Include the `Default-568h@2x.png` will make your app fill the screen on 4" retina devices.

The web browser view of the PhoneGrap should fill the screen.

Comment: For the config.xml (phonegap build) 
<gap:splash src="images/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

Comment: Or in the case of the current version I'm using, the SRC is "res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"