# Iphone5: Black screen appearing at the top and bottom when running ios5 application on ios6

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PhoneGap and iPhone 5: Remove top and bottom black stripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508775/phonegap-and-iphone-5-remove-top-and-bottom-black-stripes)

Please enlighten me on this.
When i run my ios5 app on ios6 retina 4 inch simulator i can see a black screen at the top and bottom of the simulator. please help me in resolving this issue..

Comment: Read the apple documentation about this lol...\

Answer (score 0):

You must include a default splash screen image for iPhone 5. This acts as a flag, tells the device that your app is set up for the 4 inch display.

name of image must be: Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: Yes i have tried this thing but isn't working....